# Check CoreData against todays date

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to hide the "Hide me" text in the content view when there is a CoreData record with a "CreatedAt" Attribute (date) that matches todays date.

**DiaryItem.swift**

```
public class DiaryItem:NSManagedObject,Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var createdAt:Date?
    @NSManaged public var title:String?
}

extension DiaryItem {
    static func getAllDiaryItems() -> NSFetchRequest<DiaryItem> {
       let request:NSFetchRequest<DiaryItem> = DiaryItem.fetchRequest() as!       NSFetchRequest<DiaryItem>

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)

    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return request
    }
}
```

Simplified **ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

@FetchRequest(entity: DiaryItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \DiaryItem.createdAt, ascending: false),
]) var diaryItems : FetchedResults<DiaryItem>

@State var show = false
@State private var showEntry: Bool = false

var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Text("Hide me!")

            List{

                ForEach(self.diaryItems) { diaryItem in

                    DiaryItemView(
                        title: diaryItem.title!,
                        createdAt: "\(diaryItem.createdAt!)",
                        diaryItem: diaryItem
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can compare two dates like below:

```
var first = Date()  

let isToday = Calendar.current.isDateInToday(first)
```

How do I check if the user has already created a CoreData record with a CreatedAt date that matches the current day and hide the "Hide me" text if it does?

Thanks for reading any help would be amazing!

Comment: Please explain some more - what exactly is it you are trying to hide, and when?  (Hide something in every row? Or hide something elsewhere in the view?)

Comment: @pbasdf thanks for getting in touch. I'd like to hide the "Hide me" text in the content view.

Comment: To help you more information on what are the conditions to hide that text is needed, like pbasdf already wrote. Just hiding your text would work with the `hidden()`modifier like this: `Text("Hide me!").hidden()`. But I do not think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @user3687284 Thanks - The conditions is if the user has already created a CoreData record that has a CreatedAt date that is the same day as the current date then I want to hide the "Hide me" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your `Text("Hide me")` with the following, it should suppress the text if the first item in your list (ie. the most recent, as you have `ascending: false`) is in today:

```
if (diaryItems.first == nil || Calendar.current.isDateInToday(diaryItems.first!.createdAt!)) {
    Text("Hide me!")
    }
```

Things will get more complicated if some diaryItems' `createdAt` could be in the future.

Comment: That works beautifully for what I need thank you so much! Only problem is the app crashes if there is no diaryItems. Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: If there are no diaryItems, should "Hide me" be displayed, or hidden?

Comment: If there are no diary items It should be displayed. Thanks.

Comment: I (lazily) used ! to unwrap, which fails if diaryItems is empty.  So I have updated the answer to include a specific check to see whether it is nil.